# Spring-batch how reader transaction works

Tags: transactions, spring-batch

Im using spring-batch and in my situation I need to use pessimistic lock.
Since the docs said the `pagingitemeader` will use a seperate transaction so that items can be cached, I chose to lock the item in processor.At that time, I use `JdbcPagingItemReader` and `ItemWriter`.
But when I turn to use `MybatisPagingItemReader` and `MybatisBatchItemWriter`,I found the first chunk commit after reader transaction is in the same transaction with reader！
For example here are ten items to be processed,the chunksize is 2 and the pagesize is 5.In spring-batch after second commit,it will execute the second read.In this case the 1,2,5,6 items will be commited in the same transaction with read as shown in the pics.How does it happen？[enter image description here][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/don0M.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/don0M.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyeDT.jpg)

Comment: `I need to use pessimistic lock.` What, specifically, do you mean by that? Spring Batch uses an optimistic locking strategy when interacting with the job repository, so you need to make sure that what you are trying to do is compatible with that.

Comment: `the docs said the pagingitemeader will use a seperate transaction [..] At that time, I use JdbcPagingItemReader [.. ] But when I turn to use MybatisPagingItemReader and MybatisBatchItemWriter,I found the first chunk commit after reader transaction is in the same transaction with reader`: What is this `MybatisPagingItemReader`? Are you sure it is using a separate transaction? This reader is not provided by Spring Batch so the issue is not in Spring Batch. Do you have the same issue with the `JdbcPagingItemReader`? If yes, please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the behavior shown in the pic is caused by mybatis sqlSession.Thank u for your help